# Android Save and check, radio button

Tags: java, android, preferences

Sorry for my bad english.

I have 2 classes,

1 `MainActivity.java` (Standard)
2 `settings.java` (for settings)

I have a `RadioGroup` with 5 `Radiobuttons`.

I save the state of the radio buttons as follows (in to settings.java class):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("status", 0); 
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    editor.putBoolean("blue", blue.isChecked());
    editor.putBoolean("orange", orange.isChecked());
    editor.putBoolean("purple", purple.isChecked());
    editor.putBoolean("grey", grey.isChecked());
    editor.putBoolean("green", green.isChecked());
    editor.commit();

}


public void loadSettings () {



    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("status", 0);

    royalBlue.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("blue", false)); 
    orange.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("orange", false));
    purple.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("purple", false));
    titan.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("grey", false));
    eighties.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("green", false));

}
```

the status of the radio buttons is saved successfully. Even after a restart of the app the radio button is saved.

I would like now when the `RadioButton` orange (or other) is selected, the `ImageButton` will change my image. I would like to make in the `MainActivity`.

I have tried it in the Main Activity so but I always get a `NullPoinException`:

Code from the Main ...

```
private settings load = new settings();
...
...
public void change (){
   if (load.orange.isChecked()){
        imBuOn.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange);
    }
```

as I said I can so unfortunately unable to access the status of the radio button.

Do I need to maybe use `PreferenceManager`? how shall I put it best?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch the SharedPreferences in the MainActivity and then setting the ImageView?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create an instance of the `settings` class and fetch the value of the `checkBox`. Instead, you should just use the same code as given in the `loadSettings` method since you are just accessing the `SharedPreferences` file.

So, in your MainActivity, just run this

```
private void checkAndSetImage()
{
     SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("status", 0);
     if(settings.getBoolean("orange", false))
     {
         imBuOn.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange);
     }
}
```

Just call this function to wherever applicable.